# freezing python program

Tags: python, dependencies, pyinstaller, freeze, cx-freeze

I have written a script where user can send mails to multiple addresses. It is an alternative to Mail Merge. The structure of the program is as follows:

```
server.py      --- Starts python server and opens index.html which is forms
cgi-bin/min.py --- captures the form fields and create email for users with text input
```

Now I wish to freeze and convert it to exe for using on windows without python installation. I used `pyinstaller/py2exe/cx_freeze` but not getting end result.

The script for `setup.py` for `cx_freeze` is as follows

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
   name = "ravi shankar",
   version = "3.6",
   description = "a mail merge tool.",
   executables = [Executable("server.py", base = "Win32GUI")])
```

Comment: What error are you getting in cx_Freeze?

Comment: cgi-bin/min.py is not getting converted.  It is included in the form action of index.html

Comment: Any Error tracebacks?

Comment: It may not be error of cx_Freeze. I am not able to find how to package the server.py, cgi-bin/min.py and index.html as one package. On clicking submit  the index page is opening again instead of executing cgi-bin/min.py

Comment: Go for Pyinstaller then.  I think that is you best option.